# Invalidate all user sessions using express-sessions and knex

Tags: node.js, knex.js, express-session

I have inherited a Express site which needs some updating. There is a route for resetting password, but I need to invalidate all the users sessions when this happen and allow for auto login on the current browser at the same time.
I'm kinda new to Express, so can anybody point me in the direction of a guide?

Setting up of sessionStore:

```
const sessionStore = knexSession(session)
const store = new sessionStore({
  knex: db
})
app.use(session({
  secret: sessionKey,
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  store,
  cookie: {
    maxAge: null,
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: app.get('env') !== 'development' || app.get('port') === 443,
  }
}))
```

Resetting password:

```
let data = {
  password,
  token: null,
  expires: null
}

return models.user.update(user.id, user.id, data)
   .then(_ => {
     //reset session user sessions
    //only invalidates the current session
    req.logout()
    req.session.destroy(function (err) {
      res.clearCookie('connect.sid')
      res.redirect('/')
    });
})
```